# Salesforce Data Event for multiple criterias

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I just created a Journey with a Salesforce Data Event. The criteria to inject the customers is:

- The value of a field A has been updated to 'True'
- A new record is created and the value of the field A is 'True'

How can I set the entry event to cover both use cases?

- If I set the entry criteria as 'Is Updated' plus field A = 'True' new
  records with the field A as 'True' are not injected.
- If I set the entry criteria as 'Is Updated' and 'Is Created' plus field A = 'True' all new records in the object are injected plus the one with the field A updated as 'True'.

Comment: 'Is Updated' and 'Is Created' plus field A =true > this is correct. all newly created records with A=true, as well as older records updated to A=true will be injected into the journey

Comment: but not the new records when the field A = false, right?

Comment: yes, that's right. just new records with field A = true